# What does this line of Typescript mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend

I am learning some Typescript from scratch. Here is some code from their official website. I'm confused with one line in below.What does this declaration mean here? the {} after equal sign means return type is void?

```
var validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
module Validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }

    var lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;

    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }

    export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}

// Some samples to try
var strings = ['Hello', '98052', '101'];
// Validators to use
var validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};
validators['ZIP code'] = new Validation.ZipCodeValidator();
validators['Letters only'] = new Validation.LettersOnlyValidator();
// Show whether each string passed each validator
strings.forEach(s => {
    for (var name in validators) {
        console.log('"' + s + '" ' + (validators[name].isAcceptable(s) ? ' matches ' : ' does not match ') + name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line...

```
var validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};
```

is broken down as:

- `var validators` - declare a variable
- `{ [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; }` this is type information. The type of this variable is a hash. The parts here are `{ [type of key]: type of value }`. So, this is a hash of strings to `Validation.StringValidator`.
- `= {}` This is the initial value of the variable: An empty hash.

If I wanted to make a hash of numbers to strings, I would use

```
var myHash: { [key: number]: string } = {};
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand the first and third points. For the 2nd point, you mentioned a hash; can I say it is declaring something like a dictionary with a string as key? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes. It is a dictionary with a string key and a value of type `Validation.StringValidator`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your confirmation! I will grant you the credit!!!

Comment: var myHash: { [key: number]: string } = {}; just one quick thing, do you think [key:number] the brackets here are required? is it the literal stuff required by TS?

Comment: @catlovespurple It's real TypeScript syntax, if that's what you're asking. This is how you declare the type of a dictionary. If you don't want to impose type restrictions on your dictionary, don't use this syntax. The square brackets are part of the syntax, they are not optional.

Comment: Got it! that's exactly what I'm asking, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know TypeScript, but I do know ECMAScript, of which TypeScript is a superset, and in ECMAScript, curly braces denote an object literal, so, this assigns an empty object to the variable `validators`.

On the next two lines, the empty object is filled with some key-value mappings.

Comment: yes the curly braces create an empty object. Get any chance to know this part? - [s : string] : Validation.StringValidator? I feel like it passed a string object as the parameter to the StringValidator ctor.